# I can't update the formset

Tags: django, django-forms

I cannot update using an inline form.
I thought it was possible before, but it wasn't.
I'm trying to solve it, but it doesn't work.
I added.
I will post any other necessary items.
**"Id
This field is required.
user
A Profile with this User already exists.
"**
I got an error.

```
#view

class UserEdit(generic.UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = forms.UserUpdateForm
    template_name = 'accounts/accounts_edit.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('person:myaccount')

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.request.user.user_id)
```

```
#model
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
      username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()

      user_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid_lib.uuid4,
                              primary_key=True, editable=False)
      username = models.CharField(_('username'), unique=True, max_length=50,validators=[username_validator],error_messages={
              'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
          },)

class profile(models.Model):
      image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile/',default='profile/default.jpg')
      first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True,null=True)
      last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=150, blank=True,null=True)
      birthday = models.DateField(_('birthday',),null=True)
      user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
```

```
#form
class ProfileUpdateForm(BaseModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = profile
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','birthday',)

ProfileFormSet = inlineformset_factory(User,profile,form=ProfileUpdateForm,extra=0)


class UserUpdateForm(mixins.ModelFormWithFormSetMixin,BaseModelForm):

    formset_class = ProfileFormSet
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email',)
```

```
#mixin
class ModelFormWithFormSetMixin:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ModelFormWithFormSetMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.formset = self.formset_class(

            instance=self.instance,

            data=self.data if self.is_bound else None,
        )

    def is_valid(self):
        return super(ModelFormWithFormSetMixin, self).is_valid() and self.formset.is_valid()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        saved_instance = super(ModelFormWithFormSetMixin, self).save(commit)
        self.formset.save(commit)
        return saved_instance
```

Comment: You shouldn't use an  inlineformset for a OneToOne relation. Just use two forms in your view, one for the profile, one for user.

Comment: But if you really want to, and it's not working, you'll need to show us the code for `ModelFormWithFormSetMixin`.

Comment: I added. Please.

Comment: Your `ProfileUpdateForm` needs to have the `id` of the profile as field, otherwise the formset will not know you're updating an existing profile rather than creating a new one. Add `id` to the fields and override it to be a hidden input field.

Comment: I'm sorry. I made it function-based because of my lack of power.